# Moving states inside a tensor (QuTip)

Tags: python, qutip

I have a qutip tensor as follows:

```
psi = constants*tensor(fock(N,0),fock(N,1),fock(N,2))
```

I need a way to swap the positions of the third state with the second state such that the structure becomes:

```
psi = (some operation on psi)
psi = constants*tensor(fock(N,0),fock(N,2),fock(N,1))
```

I need it to maintain the ket nature of psi, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`permute()`](https://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/classes.html?highlight=perm#qutip.Qobj.permute) method

```py
N = 10
psi = tensor(fock(N, 0), fock(N, 1), fock(N, 2))
goal_psi = tensor(fock(N, 0), fock(N, 2), fock(N, 1))
new_psi = psi.permute([0, 2, 1])
isequal(new_psi, goal_psi)
```